# Graphing from a file

Tags: plotting, files-and-directories

I have a lot experience with traditional programming languages, but almost none with mathematica. I have data that I've transformed and saved to a file in the format

{x,y,time}

{x,y,time}

...

Where x and y are the data I want on the x and y axis, and "time" is a timestamp where each dataset should be its own line. The only "interesting" part of the data is that they're all incredibly small numbers, so they look like "1.00E-010" along the y-axis and I don't know if this will be a problem.

I've tried to use ReadList and then ArrayReshape, but I honestly don't have a good idea as to what I'm doing. Any help, or just a direction to look in, would be huge.

For the record I can modify the formatting of the file somewhat if it's helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: You want all of the x,y pairs with the same time value to be plotted on a separate plot?

Comment: I'm hoping to plot the lines on the same graph, with each line being a different time.

Comment: So you want a single plot with all of the x,y pairs that have the same time value assigned a different color or label on the plot?

Comment: That would be ideal, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want a single plot with all of the `x,y` pairs that have the same `time` value assigned a different color / label then it would be easier if the format of the data is just CSV, remove the curly braces.

```
rawData = Import["~/data.csv", "CSV"];
groupedData = MapAt[Most, GroupBy[rawData, Last], {All, All}];
ListLinePlot[Values[groupedData], PlotLegends -> Keys[groupedData]]
```

May have to be changed depending on the format of `time`

Comment: It looks like that would work, but I've left it running for over an hour and it's still trying to resolve. The file is about 50,000 lines with 3 columns which doesn't seem excessive for a modern computer. Is there any reason mathematica would hang so hard on this?

Comment: @Jay  That seems excessively long. I would abort evaluation and check if the data was imported correctly. `Length[groupedData]` is the number of distinct time values. Is it what you expect? If not then something is wrong with the grouping. What exactly is the format of the `time` column? You can also try plotting a small subset of the values and make sure it looks right. `ListLinePlot[Take[Values[groupedData], 10], 
 PlotLegends -> Take[Keys[groupedData], 10]]`

Comment: Simply moving the directory to something else and then putting it back fixed the error. I don't know why it was being a problem. Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: @Jay Great. I would appreciate it if you could [upvote and accept](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer. Thanks!